# How to call a function when drag in carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

By the way this code is work as well but one more thing I want to alert() or call a function when user click to drag a item of carousel.
I have read document to used Carousel event but I still can't find the result 
I will using this ***drag.owl.carousel dragged.owl.carousel*** option to alert or call a function but it can't work for me.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "<?php echo base_url('main/data/12'); ?>",
   dataType: "json",
   cache: false,
   success: function (data, st) {
       if (st == 'success') {
             $.each(data, function (i, obj) {
                  var out = '<div class="row item">';
                  out += '<div class="product">';
                  out += '<div class="image">';
                  out += '<a href=""><img src="asset/img/main/9.jpg" alt="img" class="img-responsive"></a>';
                  out += '<div class="promotion"><span class="discount">' + obj.prodId + '</span> </div>';
                  out += '<div class="description"><div class="price"><span>' + obj.prodPrice + '</span></div><h4><a href="#">' + obj.prodName + '</a></h4>';
                  out += '<p>short detial</p>';
                  out += '</div>';
                  out += '</div>';
                  $(out).appendTo(".owl-carousel");
              });
      }
      var owl = $(".owl-carousel");
      owl.on( 'drag.owl.carousel dragged.owl.carousel', function(e) {
             alert(e);
      });
      owl.owlCarousel({
          loop: true,
          nav: true,
          lazyLoad: true,
          margin: 10,
          video: true,
          responsive: {
             0: {
                 items: 1
               },
             600: {
                items: 3
                },
             960: {
                items: 5,
             },
             1200: {
                items: 6
            }
         }
       });
     }
    });
```

Comment: Could not reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/ug04guLw/

Comment: Ok thanks I have to update Carousel version because I'm currently version 1.3 so it will be work when I upgrade to 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine with Owl Carousel 2.x. If you must use version 1, you can supply the event listener in the initialization object as the `startDragging` property:

```
owl.owlCarousel({
    loop: true,

    startDragging: function(e) {
        alert(e);
    },

    ...
});
```